# How to determine the most recent Tournament, that was today or in the past, that has at least 3 Result entries in Rails 6.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Models: Tournaments, Results

```
class Tournament < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :results

end

class Result < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tournament

end
```

I currently have the following to achieve "Determine the most recent tournament date that is either today or in the past":

```
last_tournament = Tournament.where("tournament_date <= ?", Date.today).order(tournament_date: :desc).limit(1)[0]
```

But I want to add to this ..."and has at least 3 result entries". Other homepage code depends on "last tournament" and it makes it easier if it does not try to analyze data that has not been entered yet, as soon as it turns midnight.

I was thinking it would use .joins() with Result and Tournament but I think I need to use .count on Result and that throws off me off, I'm having so trouble figuring out a solution.

Maybe a do loop that rolls out a desc order of the last tournaments and an if statement that checks if that Result(tournament_id : x).count >= 3? Is there a one-liner thats clean for this solution?

thanks.

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question. Multiple questions rolled into one are very hard to answer and have a very diffuse scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the rows by tournaments.id and use HAVING to set a condition on the group:

```
Tournament
  .joins(:results)
  .where(tournament_date: ..Date.today)
  .order(tournament_date: :desc)
  .group(:id)
  .having(Result.arel_table[:id].count.gteq(3))
  .limit(1)
```